# Showing $A$ is similar to a diagonal matrix but not unitarily similar to a diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
0&1&-1\\
-1&-2&5\\
0&0&3
\end{bmatrix}
$$

i) Prove that $A$ is similar to a diagonal matrix, but not unitarily similar to a diagonal matrix.

ii) Find two $A-$invariant subspaces $V_1$ and $V_2$ such that $\mathbb{R}^3$ is the direct sum $V_1$ and $V_2$.

I know that $spec(A)=\{-1,3\}$ and its characteristic polynomial is $p(x)=(x-3)(x+1)^2$. We also have Schur's theorem , but I don't know how to solve the probelm. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clear that $\dim \ker(A + I) = 3 - \operatorname{rank}(A + I) = 1$ so the geometric multiplicity of the eigenvalue $-1$ is one and $A$ is not diagonalizable. A direct sum decomposition of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is given by
$$\mathbb{R}^3 = \ker(A + I)^2 \oplus \ker(A - 3I)$$
and each (generalized) eigenspace is $A$-invariant.

The matrix $A$ is not orthogonally similar to a diagonal matrix because it is diagonalizable so it is definitely not orthogonally diagonalizable.

Comment: sorry I didn't get why $A$ is  similar to a diagonal. Yes it's eigenvalues are -1,3, and it's jordan form would be $$\begin{bmatrix}  -1&-1&0\\0&-1&0\\0&0&3 \end{bmatrix}$$.

Comment: @Parisina: Yeah, sorry, the rank is $1$ and not $2$. I've fixed my answer.

Comment: the questions says that $A$ is similar to a diagonal but not unitarily simialr to a diagonal matrix. However, since algebraic multiplicity of eigenvalue $-1$ is not equal to its geometric multiplicity, the matrix $A$ is not diagonalizable . I think there is a problem. Right?

Comment: Indeed, the question as stated is wrong.